# How To Check Whether A URL Is External URL or Internal URL With PHP?

Tags: php, html, backend

I'm getting all ahrefs of a page with this loop:

```
foreach($html->find('a[href!="#"]') as $ahref) {
    $ahrefs++;
}
```

I want to do something like this:

```
foreach($html->find('a[href!="#"]') as $ahref) {
    if(isexternal($ahref)) {
        $external++;
    }
    $ahrefs++;
}
```

Where isexternal is a function

```
function isexternal($url) {
    // FOO...

    // Test if link is internal/external
    if(/*condition is true*/) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Help!

Comment: External or internal to what? The site the page was scraped from?

Comment: I think that is what he means. Like"Is it a cross-website link ?"

Comment: Suppose there is a site: xyz.com... If it links a link to another site abc.com, then this link should be marked as external. But if, its with same domain (xyz.com) or local URL, then it should not fall in external

Comment: as you have the $html var filled, it means you know the domain name, right ?

Comment: Yep. I've got every < a > link with its href + domain name as well. Just I want to know how do I make it separate from same domain URLs.

Comment: but do you know from where you get this html code ? (if it the the html from abc.com, do you have a var `$site == 'abc.com'` ?)

Comment: Sir I've got everything ready.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use [parse_url](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and compare host to your local host (often but not always it's the same as `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`)

```
function isexternal($url) {
  $components = parse_url($url);    
  return !empty($components['host']) && strcasecmp($components['host'], 'example.com'); // empty host will indicate url like '/relative.php'
}
```

Hovewer this will treat [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) and example.com as different hosts. If you want all your subdomains to be treated as local links then the function will be somewhat larger:

```
function isexternal($url) {
  $components = parse_url($url);
  if ( empty($components['host']) ) return false;  // we will treat url like '/relative.php' as relative
  if ( strcasecmp($components['host'], 'example.com') === 0 ) return false; // url host looks exactly like the local host
  return strrpos(strtolower($components['host']), '.example.com') !== strlen($components['host']) - strlen('.example.com'); // check if the url host is a subdomain
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this is trouble free, if some links contain www., some not. You should erase www. (or other subdomains), if they are in the host-value.

Comment: The check for the subdomain is not reliable.
e.g.
theexample.com will match with example.com

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can simply detect external URLs:

```
$url    = 'https://my-domain.com/demo/';
$domain = 'my-domain.com';

$internal = (
    false !== stripos( $url, '//' . $domain ) || // include "//my-domain.com" and "http://my-domain.com"
    stripos( $url, '.' . $domain ) ||            // include subdomains, like "www.my-domain.com". DANGEROUS (see below)!
    (
        0 !== strpos( $url, '//' ) &&            // exclude protocol relative URLs, like "//example.com"
        0 === strpos( $url, '/' )                // include root-relative URLs, like "/demo"
    )
);
```

The above check will treat `www.my-domain.com` and `my-domain.com` as being "internal".

**Why this rule is dangerous**:

The subdomain logic introduces a weakness that could be exploited: When an external URL contains your domain inside the path, for example, `https://external.com/www.my-domain.com` is treated as internal!

**More secure code**:

This problem can be eliminated by removing subdomain support (which I suggest to do):

```
$url    = 'https://my-domain.com/demo/';
$domain = 'my-domain.com';

$internal = (
    false !== stripos( $url, '//' . $domain ) || // include "//my-domain.com" and "http://my-domain.com"
    (
        0 !== strpos( $url, '//' ) &&            // exclude protocol relative URLs, like "//example.com"
        0 === strpos( $url, '/' )                // include root-relative URLs, like "/demo"
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is old but here my function i coded right now. Maybe some other need it too.

```
function IsResourceLocal($url){
    if( empty( $url ) ){ return false; }
    $urlParsed = parse_url( $url );
    $host = $urlParsed['host'];
    if( empty( $host ) ){ 
    /* maybe we have a relative link like: /wp-content/uploads/image.jpg */
    /* add absolute path to begin and check if file exists */
    $doc_root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
    $maybefile = $doc_root.$url;
    /* Check if file exists */
    $fileexists = file_exists ( $maybefile );
    if( $fileexists ){
        /* maybe you want to convert to full url? */
        return true;        
        }
     }
    /* strip www. if exists */
    $host = str_replace('www.','',$host);
    $thishost = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    /* strip www. if exists */
    $thishost = str_replace('www.','',$thishost);
    if( $host == $thishost ){
        return true;
        }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: If you use a web framework you should also check if this is a valid local route like "/2017/10/some-nice-post". But usually, frameworks have a method like this already. BTW,
`str_replace('www.','',$host);` needs to be done only if it's in the beginning

Answer (score 0):

```
function isexternal($url) {
    // FOO...

    // Test if link is internal/external
    if(strpos($url,'domainname.com') !== false || strpos($url,"/") === '0') 
    {
         return true;
    }
    else 
    {
         return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: it will treat www.ihackeddomainname.com the same as www.domainname.com. Besides strpos($url,"/") === '0' will never match

Comment: bad answer, for the reason mentioned above me ^

Comment: what if the url string is a relative link? bad answer

Comment: what if the url contain your url as args, like: http://someapidomain.com/callapi/?url=yourdomain.com
this will return true in your function

Comment: @RuslanBes, `strpos($url,"/") === '0' will never match` this is true for root-relative URLs (relative to current domain). However, it will also misinterpret protocol relative URLs such as`//example.com/page`

Answer (score -2):

You probably want to check if the link is in the same domain. That will only work though if all your href attributes are absolute and contain the domain. Relative ones like /test/file.html are tricky because one can have folders that have the same name as domains.. So, if you have full url's in each link:

```
function isexternal($url) {

  // Test if link is internal/external
  if(stristr($url, "myDomain.com") || strpos($url,"/") == '0')
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}
```

Comment: If the a[href] begins with /, mark it as internal. Please update the code.

Comment: in fact, if it begin with '/' it is absolute. relative is from where the html is located. 'img/img1.png' can mean '/shared/img/img1.png' for instance.

Comment: Yes, it's added. Thread opener said it would contain the domain.
@Apolo: He wants to know which ones are external; in that manner its ok to do it like that. It does not matter if the path is absolute or relative, as long as its in the same domain space.

Comment: Yep. I don't care. As long as the domain contains the hostname of the testing domain, mark it as internal. That means if abc.com is being tested, mark every domain starting WITHOUT http and not containing abc.com and EVERY link with domain host name as NON EXTERNAL and vice versa for EXTERNAL.

Comment: @MehulMohan `//evilhost.example.com` starts with `/` and is, in many contexts valid as url... Don't blindly assume that `/` guarantees absolute, same-host paths!