# Adding an onclick jquery event to links that go to external sites

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I need to add Google Analytics event tracking to all links that go to external domains.

I think I've almost wrote the code but I don't know where to add the `!=`, so far I have the below:

```
 $('a').click (function(){
     if(window.location.href.indexOf("http://mydomain.com") >1 && $(this).attr("id")){
         _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'extlink', 'click', $(this).attr('id'),0,true]);
     } else {
         _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'extlink', 'click', $(this).attr('href'),0,true]);
     }
 });
```

Comment: I think this topic can be very helpful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22964579/how-to-check-whether-a-url-is-external-url-or-internal-url-with-php

Comment: You will have to translate it to JS. :/

Comment: So you need to track only clicks on links that point to other domains?

Comment: Yes Ashesh, that's correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the JQuery selector to get only those links not going to your domain:

```
$('a:not([href^="http://mydomain.com"])').on('click', function() {
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'extlink', 'click', this.href, 0, true]);
});
```

Although, if you want external links, I'd think those would be the ones that start with "http://":

```
$('a[href^="http://"]').on('click', function() {
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'extlink', 'click', this.href, 0, true]);
});
```

Comment: The problem is I can't be 100% sure if internal links start with http or not.

Comment: `$('a[href^="http://"]').not('[href^="http://mydomain.com"]').on('click', function() {})`