# WordPress/php if statement within an if statement

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I'm having one of those moments where I know I'm so close, and probably missing something super minor that's causing this to not work.

I'm using a pre-built theme, with an if statement for including or not including a link. What I want to do it put an if statement inside of THAT differentiating between internal and external links, opening external links in a new tab.

This is the portion I'm specifically working on

```
if(!empty($parallax_one_service_box->title)){
    if( !empty($parallax_one_service_box->link) ){
            if($parallax_one_service_box->link_type == 'External'){
                echo '<h3 class="colored-text"><a href="'.esc_url($parallax_one_service_box->link).'" target="_blank">'.esc_attr($parallax_one_service_box->title).'</a></h3>';
            }else {
                echo '<h3 class="colored-text"><a href="'.esc_url($parallax_one_service_box->link).'">'.esc_attr($parallax_one_service_box->title).'</a></h3>';
            }                
    }             
    else {
            if (function_exists ( 'icl_translate' ) && !empty($parallax_one_service_box->id)){
                    echo '<h3 class="colored-text">'.icl_translate('Featured Area',$parallax_one_service_box->id.'_services_title',esc_attr($parallax_one_service_box->title)).'</h3>';
            } else {
                    echo '<h3 class="colored-text">'.esc_attr($parallax_one_service_box->title).'</h3>';
            }
    }
}
```

So it's something along the lines of "if not empty, if external link open in a new tab." I ran it through php code checker, and the code is correct...not missing any brackets or anything. The problem seems to be that it's either opening all in a new tab or opening none in a new tab...it's not differentiating between external and internal. So I'm guessing something is wrong with the "if external" line...

Here's a link to Pastebin with the whole section of code: http://pastebin.com/kmuGiVJv

Comment: Try checking the value of $parallax_one_service_box->link_type (with some echo or var_dump).

Comment: Did a var_dump and got:

    object(stdClass)#593 (7) { ["icon_value"]=> string(21) "icon-ecommerce-graph3" ["text"]=> string(197) "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla nec purus feugiat, molestie ipsum et, consequat nibh. Etiam non elit dui. Nullam vel eros sit amet arcu vestibulum accumsan in in leo." ["link"]=> string(21) "http://www.google.com" ["image_url"]=> string(0) "" ["choice"]=> string(13) "parallax_icon" ["title"]=> string(11) "Lorem Ipsum" ["id"]=> string(0) "" }


So it didn't get the 'target="_blank"' at all...

Comment: I don't see any "link_type" in that object. Is there any documentation related to the definition of that object?

Comment: I guess you could try something like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22964579/how-to-check-whether-a-url-is-external-url-or-internal-url-with-php

Comment: I would try to use all lowercase letters for comparing strings.